# jQuery bind a function to a button with an on method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I want to bind a function to a button with the .on method. Here is my button:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-offset-2 col-md-4" type="button" id="reg">Register</button>
```

And here is my script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#reg").on("click", function(){
    alert("Its working!!!");
});
});
```

I know that my code is not wrong, but I still can't make it work.... I have include all the libraries in my `<head>`. But the button does nothing.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. Are you adding button dynamically?

Comment: It is working http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/tyrdc59w/

Comment: Here is my head:

`<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="Scripts/DataCheck.js"></script>
</head>`

Answer (score 1):

You are not wrong your code is working fine

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#reg").on("click", function(){
    alert("Its working!!!");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary col-md-offset-2 col-md-4" type="button" id="reg">Register</button>
```

Comment: i think you forgotten include Jquery(js file) in your html...! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If button adding dynamically try to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").on("click", "#reg", function(){
      alert("Its working!!!");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add the jquery library in head tag and it will work fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please use that code <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#reg").on("click", function(){
    alert("Its working!!!");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="btn btn-primary col-md-offset-2 col-md-4" type="button" id="reg">Register</button>
left side
</body>
</html>